# Android create directory + sub (or) child directory in internal storage

Tags: android, storage

> I am currently working with internal storage

- I have some problems

**I am trying to create child directory in internal storage,like 
data/data/com.example.app/ parentfolder / childfolder / sample.mp4**

> Here my code was

```
    ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(context);
    File parentpath = cw.getDir("parentfolder ",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    File childpath = new File(parentpath ,"childfolder");
    File childfolder = new File(childpath,"sample.mp4");
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(childfolder);
```

Some logical mistake for that,its cannot create childfolder, Its reflect some error....

Comment: Never tell your errors. One could abuse them.

Comment: Any another idea to create childfolder?

Comment: Afraid for abuse indeed.

Comment: `File childfolder = new File(childpath,"sample.mp4");`?? Why are you calling a File variable for a mp4 file `childFolder`?

Comment: I dont understand you.

Answer (score 2):

> **And finally i got the answer**

```
//Save Internal Storage

File myMainDir = context.getDir("MainFolder", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

File mySubjectDir = new File(myMainDir, subFolder);
mySubjectDir.mkdir();

File myModuleDir = new File(mySubjectDir, semiSubFolder);
myModuleDir.mkdir();

File myFinalDir = new File(mySubjectDir, fileName);

//Save External Storage

String DNAME = "MainFolder"+"/"+subFolder+"/"+semiSubFolder;
File rootPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(), DNAME);
if(!rootPath.exists()) {
    rootPath.mkdirs();
}

if(!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
    Log.v("Cannot use storage","Cannot use storage");
}

File myFinalDir = new File(rootPath,TopicName);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
File file = new File(location);
file.mkdirs();
```